# SSH certificates and mutual authentication

Tags: authentication, ssh, mutual

SSH certificates are a recent addition to the protocol, and I see them as being used mostly for the clients.

Can the server use an SSH certificate too?

And if so, is it possible to have mutual SSH authentication between a client and a server, all done via certificates?

Comment: The certificates used by OpenSSH are not recent; it has implemented them since 5.5 in 2010 at least. But they are a nonstandard extension, so I wouldn't describe them as in 'the protocol'. They do support both host=server and user=client authentication; see [the man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1#CERTIFICATES)

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me understand why they are non-standard?

Comment: Trivially, they are nonstandard because they aren't defined in the documents that define the standard. AFAIK the OpenSSH people have never proposed them to be standardized; I don't know why not. Maybe they like having greater flexibility to change (although a standard could allow extension, as the base protocol already does), maybe they don't think there's sufficient need, maybe they even think the current scheme might be dropped (although after 10+ years that seems unlikely). No one else proposed it either; if you identify someone that you think should have, you could ask them why not.